# Arctoolbox Spatial join returns null value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am trying to join a polygon shapefine with DWG annotation, with ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 but all the fields returned are Null !! [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest converting your CAD annotation to geodatabase annotation and trying again. Here is an Esri knowledge base article on how to do so: http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/19961